# Crear .Json con Python

Tags: python, json

Tengo el siguiente resultado de una consulta :

```
((20, 'Ginecologia', 695, 'Consulta Medica'), (8, 'Cirugia Pediatrica', 693, 'Conn Y Fajans. Prueba De'), (20, 'Ginecologia', 691, 'Conizacion De Cuello (Como Unica Practica).'))
```

Quiero convertirlo a un Json del siguiente formato

```
[
    {
        "Id": 20,
        "Especialidad": "Ginecologia",
        "Practica": ['Consulta Medica','Conizacion De Cuello (Como Unica Practica).']
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Especialidad": "Cirugia Pediatrica",
        "Practica": ['Conn Y Fajans. Prueba De']
    }
]
```

El codigo en Python es el siguiente

```py
     ###ESPECIALIDADES DEL PROFESIONAL
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT especialidad.NomEsp,especialidad.IdEsp from proesp INNER JOIN especialidad on proesp.IdEsp=especialidad.IdEsp where proesp.IdPro="'+(profesional)+'"')
            EspPro=cur.fetchall()
            print(EspPro)
            ###PRACTICA POR ESPECIALIDAD DEL PROFESIONAL
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT proesp.IdEsp,especialidad.NomEsp, prestacion.IdPrest,prestacion.NomPrest from proesp INNER JOIN especialidad on proesp.IdEsp=especialidad.IdEsp INNER JOIN proesppres on proesppres.IdProEsp=proesp.IdProEsp INNER JOIN prestacion on proesppres.IdPrest=prestacion.IdPrest where proesp.IdPro="'+(profesional)+'"')
            PraEspMed=cur.fetchall()


            praespmed={}
            praespmed=[]



            for row in EspPro:
                praespmed.append({'Id':row[1],'Especialidad': row[0],'Practica':[]})
                with open('static/practica.json', 'w') as file:
                    json.dump(praespmed, file) 

            for especialidad in praespmed:
                for practica in PraEspMed:


                    if practica[1]==especialidad['Especialidad']:
                        print('Coincidiencia :',especialidad['Especialidad'],'=',practica[3])
                        especialidad['Practica']=practica[3],
                        with open('static/practica.json', 'w') as file:
                            json.dump(praespmed, file)
```

Pero lo que obtengo es un Json donde la practica solo muestra la ultima, es decir, ginecologia que deberia tener 2 practicas, solo me muestra la segunda, esta pisandome la primera, necesitaria que me muestre las dos practicas para una misma especialidad, pero no encuentro el error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien el problema es que en

```
especialidad['Practica']=practica[3]
```

reasignas cuando deberías agregar a la lista ya existente de prácticas:

```
especialidad['Practica'].append(practica[3])
```

Partiendo de los datos de la segunda consulta solo y del ejemplo que muestras, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import json

res = ((20, 'Ginecologia', 695, 'Consulta Medica'),
       (8, 'Cirugia Pediatrica', 693, 'Conn Y Fajans. Prueba De'),
       (20, 'Ginecologia', 691, 'Conizacion De Cuello (Como Unica Practica).')
       )

praespmed = {}
for id_, esp, _, pract in res:
    if (item := praespmed.get(id_)) is not None:
        item["Practica"].append(pract)
    else:
        praespmed[id_] = {"Id": id_,
                          "Especialidad": esp,
                          "Practica": [pract]
                          }

with open('static/practica.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(list(praespmed.values()), file, indent=4)
```

Lo que genera el siguiente JSON:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "Id": 20,
>         "Especialidad": "Ginecologia",
>         "Practica": [
>             "Consulta Medica",
>             "Conizacion De Cuello (Como Unica Practica)."
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "Id": 8,
>         "Especialidad": "Cirugia Pediatrica",
>         "Practica": [
>             "Conn Y Fajans. Prueba De"
>         ]
>     }
> ]
> ```

El código es para Python >= 3.8, con operador de asignación. Para Python < 3.8 se debe usar:

```
import json

res = ((20, 'Ginecologia', 695, 'Consulta Medica'),
       (8, 'Cirugia Pediatrica', 693, 'Conn Y Fajans. Prueba De'),
       (20, 'Ginecologia', 691, 'Conizacion De Cuello (Como Unica Practica).')
       )

praespmed = {}
for id_, esp, _, pract in res:
    item = praespmed.get(id_)
    if item is not None:
        item["Practica"].append(pract)
    else:
        praespmed[id_] = {"Id": id_,
                          "Especialidad": esp,
                          "Practica": [pract]
                          }

with open('static/practica.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(list(praespmed.values()), file, indent=4)
```

en vez de generar de inicio una lista de diccionarios, uso un diccionario de diccionarios con la id de especialidad (asumo que es única por especialidad) como clave. La ventaja de hacer esto es que es mucho más eficiente buscar una clave en un diccionario (tabla hash) que iterar sobre la lista para ver si hay un diccionario correspondiente a una especialidad dada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, mas claro imposible, me resirvio